# Image swapping with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to Jquery so please excuse this noobie question. I am trying to swap a background image of an `<h1>` element when a user clicks on the corresponding hyperlink. The `<a>` tags are generated dynamically and there can be 'n' quantity of them at any time depending on how many images are set in a SQL table.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="feature-image">
    <h1><span>A random heading</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="feature-links">
    <a class="a1" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="a2" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="a3" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

The `<span>` tags are set to display:none

I've written this Jquery statement to run when a user clicks on a hyperlink in the #feature-links div. I was attempting to set the var `image` to the name of the `<a>` tags class (a1, a2, a3) etc. and then change the CSS background image property of the `<h1>` using the `image` var as part of the `.jpg.` url.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#feature-links a').click(function(){
        var image = $(this).attr("class","");
        $('#feature-image h1').css('background-image','url=(\'main_' + image + '.jpg\')');
    });
});
</script>
```

all my images are named "main_a1.jpg", "main_a2.jpg" and so on...

I can't see what I am doing wrong or whether what I am attempting to do (grab class names etc. in vars) is actually good practice or not... some help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Jquery code after edits:

```
$(function(){
    $('#feature-links a').click(function(){
        var image = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#feature-image h1').css('background-image','url(images/main_' + image + '.jpg)');
    });             
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change line to:

```
var image = $(this).attr("class");
```

I believe specifying 2 parameters to the `.attr()` function is used for changing the attribute value. Therefore in your case, it would change the class to `""`.

Specifying one parameter will return the value of the class

Comment: Thanks Curt, I've edited my post above to reflect how my code looks now. It (unfortunately) is still not working. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Spotted my error, it was with my CSS nesting. All works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A better way, instead of using the class would be to set the href.

For example:

```
$('#feature-links a').click(function(e){

    $('#feature-image h1').css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('href') + ')'
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // Stops the standard link behaviour

});
```

Then your links would simply link directly to the background image:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg">1</a>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I like this solution, I wanted to go with this previously but found myself using things I 'sort of' knew how to do. Even so I can't get this to work... running it through firebug finds no errors but the image stays the same :(